# How to add post data into already exist array in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a contact form. There is some code from the confirm page and the final page with the 'your message has been sent' message controller code.

I need to add a couple of post data to the 'confirm' page.

How do I recieve those post data and add them to the `$data` array at the complete function?

```php
/*
* confirm page
*/
public function confirm(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [];
    $this->validate($request, $rules); 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    $request->session()->put('data',$data);
    dd($request);
    return view('mail.confirm', compact("data"));
}

/*
*　final page (your message has been sent page)
*/
public function complete(Request $request)
{ 
    $data = $request->session()->pull('data');
    $token = array_shift($data);
    $Contact = Contact::create($data);

    $data = session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('mail.complete');
}
```

Comment: In your HTML (the blade files) you need to add new input fields. Then when posting that form the data will be automatically passed to the request body. To get the data use `$data = $request->all();`


Also, always make sure to validate the user input. You can [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add post data, you can retrieve from the `$request` variable using:

```
$request->all();
```

For your case:

```
public function complete(Request $request)
{ 
    $data = $request->session()->pull('data'); 
    $token = array_shift($data);
    $data = array_merge($data, $request->all());
    $Contact = Contact::create($data);

    $data = session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('mail.complete');
}
```

Comment: Dear @thisiskelvin Thank you for helping me. Could you teach me more please ? I'm not sure how to add your code. I'm gussing around here. right? $data = $request->session()->pull('data'); Could you add your code into mine please?

Comment: Dear @thisiskelvin THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! You are amazing! Thank you again for your kindness.